# Clear state for SWT Text Widget

Tags: java, widget, swt, state

I have this function :

```
public static void changeState(Text control,final int style)
{   
    if (SWT.ENABLED == (style & SWT.ENABLED)) {
        MyService.setState(control, SWT.ENABLED);

    }
    if (SWT.DISABLED == (style & SWT.DISABLED)) {
        MyService.setState(control, SWT.DISABLED);

    }
    if(SWT.READ_ONLY == (style & SWT.READ_ONLY)){
        MyService.setState(control, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    }
}
```

I want to clear the current state of the widget before setting another state to it.

I made a text object for which I set the state to inactive and after this I tried to set it to read_only but it didn't work and that's why I am trying to make a function which clears the current state in order to be able to change states for the same object.

How should I do this?

Maybe there is some function which does this but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such flags as `SWT.ENABLED` or `SWT.DISABLED`.

You enable/disable a control using

```
control.setEnabled(boolean);
```

You change the read only state of a `Text` control using

```
control.setEditable(boolean);
```

Note that most other style bits cannot be changed once a control has been created.

Comment: And how could I set for a widget to not have any style?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not have any style'? Many style bits cannot be changed once the control is created.

Comment: @GritcoAndreea There is no notion of telling a widget not to have a state. It just has a default state (enabled) and it can be turned off. You can get the current state via getEnabled() thou.